# ListView doesn't open a new activity in onListItemClick when I use a condition

Tags: android

```
private String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.mylist);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));


//getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}



protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String pen = o.toString();


    if (pen.equals("Android"))
    { 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Catedral.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Catedral", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger and checked the value of pen before the condition? If so what is it? The Intent calls look fine but pen is obviously not equal to "Android" if it's not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `toString` on `Object` just returns the memory reference of the object.  This is why `pen` does not match.

I'm not that familiar with `ListAdapter`,  have you tried casting the return to a `String` before assigning to a reference:

```
String pen = (String) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast `getListAdapter()` to your adapter type, which is `ArrayAdapter<String>`. This will cause `getItem` to return a `String`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListAdapter();
String pen = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Also note that it's better style to lead with your `String` literal in `equals`:

```
if ("Android".equals(pen)) {
    ....
```

This is because `pen.equals(...)` will throw a `NullPointerException` when `pen` is `null`.